# Number of permitted words up to permutation in a subshift

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics

Let $A$ be a finite set and let $X \subseteq A^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a subshift.  Let $\mathcal{L}_n$ denote the set of words of length $n$ appearing in $X$.  For a word $w \in \mathcal{L}_n$, one can define its **empirical distribution** to be the probability vector $ P_w := \left( \frac{N(a | w)}{n} \right)_{a \in A}$ where $N(a | w)$ denotes the number of occurrences of the letter $a \in A$ in the word $w$.  I am interested in the quantity $T(n) := \# \{ P_w : w \in \mathcal{L}_n \}$ (equivalently, $T(n) = \#(\mathcal{L}_n / \sim)$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $\mathcal{L}_n$ that declares two words to be equivalent if they are permutations of each other).

More specifically, I'm interested in subshifts with the property that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} T(n) = \infty$.  Is there a name for this property?  Are there any more commonly known conditions that imply this property?

Some examples/non-examples for intuition:

1. $X = \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.  All words are permitted, so $T(n) = n+1$.
2. $X \subseteq \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the SFT defined by forbidding the word $11$.  Words of length $n$ can have up to half of their entries be equal to $1$, so $T(n) \approx n/2$.
3. $X$ is the orbit closure of $\{ x \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} : x_{2i}x_{2i+1} = 01 \text{ or } 10 \text{ for all } i \}$.  Any permitted word $w$ of length $n$ has both $N(0 | w), N(1 | w) \in [n/2 - 2, n/2 + 2]$, so $T(n) \leq 5$ for all $n$.

Comment: There is an issue with this property which is that it fails to be preserved under isomorphisms. In that sense, this isn’t really a dynamical property.

Comment: As far as I understand you are looking for subshifts with unbounded abelian complexity. There is some literature on the _bounded_ case...

Comment: If I'm understanding your notation correctly, the property that $T(n)$ remains bounded is known as $C$-balancedness in the literature, or `bounded discrepancy' if the subshift has uniform letter-frequencies. As Ale De Luca mentioned, this is also called the abelian complexity of a sequence/subshift. As an example of where this is studied, Adamcewski classified the asymptotic growth rates of the function (really the discrepancy function) for all primitive substitution subshifts: https://adamczewski.perso.math.cnrs.fr/article_tcs.pdf